# Does anyone know what's happening with infinite loops and StackOverflow error while using recursive call?

Tags: java, recursion, java.util.scanner, stack-overflow

This is a part of a program I'm making for practice, its purpose doesn't really matter.
I have declared the Scanner as a field of the class** (it's not written here sorry).
I want to make a method that returns an answer specified to the users input. And I want to make all the neccesary checks needed so the user can't input a character or symbol, just an integer. When the input data is of the wrong type I want the user to try input again.

```
public static void Answer() {

System.out.println("\n\t1.It was good! \n\t2.Kinda bad too...");
System.out.println();

if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {

  int choice = scanner.nextInt();

  switch (choice) {
  case 1:
    System.out.println("Oh great!");
    break;
  case 2:
    System.out.println("I see you as well");
    break;
  default:
    System.out.println("Please select a valid answer :");
    Answer();
    break;
  } else {

    System.out.println("Please select a number, characters are not acceptable!");

    Answer();

  }
```

When I enter an invalid number like 3,4 etc the algorithm triggers the switch block and the recursive call as well, working just fine!
BUT when I enter a character it triggers an infinite recursive call **without letting me enter new input form the scanner** and ends up in **StackOverflow** error.

Answer (score 0):

You check if the Scanner has an `int`. If it does not, then it goes to the `else` branch.

In the `else` branch, it calls `Answer()` again. But here's the catch: your scanner *still* doesn't have an `int`. So `scanner.hasNextInt()` returns `false`. `hasNextInt()` does not try to read anything - it merely checks *if* there is input that can be interpreted as an `int`.
(Source: [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--)).

So the program goes again to the `else` branch, without ever reaching the point where it can try to read input... and there it calls `Answer()` again. Now, the code still doesn't have an `int`... so once again, `scanner.hasNextInt()` returns false, and it goes to the `else` branch. Once again, it does not get to the part where the scanner consumes input, but instead gets to the part where it calls `Answer()` again...

And this will continue, until the call stack is full and you get the StackOverflow error.

You'll have to take care of the situation that the user enters something that is not an `int`. You'll have to consume that input that is not an `int`.

As an aside, I'd prefer to do this using iteration, rather than recursion.

Comment: Shouldn`t it ask for an input again? When  i run it with a wrong integer the recursive call asks me for an input again instead of going infinite

Comment: When you use the wrong integer, there is an int for the Scanner. `scanner.hasNextInt()` will return `true`. But when you use a character... `scanner.hasNextInt()` will return `false`. It never reaches the `scanner.nextInt()` where it tries to consume the input.

Comment: This is what  i dont understand.When i run the method for the first time the scanner asks me for an input.When i use the recursive call it should run all over again the method and ask again for an input but it doesnt.

Comment: @nikas It never reaches `scanner.nextInt()`. It never gets to the point where it can even try to get more input. `hasNextInt()` does not read from the input. From the Java documentation (emphasis mine): "Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as an int value in the default radix using the nextInt() method. **The scanner does not advance past any input**.".

Comment: Reinstate Monica I understand.Thank you for your time!